How to show types specified in JSDoc on TypeScript while hovering over a function, method, etc in VS Code?
JSDoc allows to specify parameter types, return types and so on in the documentation. How can I set VS Code to display them when hovering over the documented code part?
For example I have this documented code in file.ts:
/**
 * A localization function returned by the {@link useLocalize} hook.
 * @param {LocalizationNames} entryName The name of the localization key.
 * @param {string?} defaultValue A default value if a localization key is not found.
 * @param {unknown} params The interpolation parameters for the localization function. E.g. `{ interpolationName: interpolationValue }`.
 * @param {boolean?} escapeValue A value indicating whether the special characters should be escaped with interpolation. The default value is `true`.
 * @returns {string} The localized string.
 */
export type LocalizeFunction = (entryName: LocalizationNames, defaultValue?: string, params?: unknown, escapeValue?: boolean) => string;

The hover info however "drops" the type definitions from the documentation, the function body description does include them:

A lot of search engines, e.g. Google: jsdoc typescript vscode @param type hover.
As a result I would expect the the hover popup to indicate the types also along the parameter names, such as:

The upper image is just a sample, it doesn't have to be in arc closures, anything will do as the types are displayed.

Probably the intention is that since the typescript declaration already includes it's redundant to also have it in the jsdoc comment. Just remove the types from the comment completely. Small nitpick: the "name of a key" is simply "the key" in a lookup table...

Okay, so the behavior is intentional rather than a flag you can switch on or off. Thanks for the bonus documentation review though @masterxilo
